# Getting a single version of data as per filters from a row-key in bigtable

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I am not able to get a single version of data from BigTable as per my filters

My table looks something like this

```
xy001uuuyyyy
  hashes:md5                               @ 2023/06/17-16:57:10.173000
    "emialmd5test"
  hashes:md5                               @ 2023/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emialmd5"
  hashes:sha1                              @ 2023/06/17-16:57:10.173000
    "emailsha1test"
  hashes:sha1                              @ 2023/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emailsha1"
  hashes:sha256                            @ 2023/06/17-16:57:10.173000
    "emailsha256test"
  hashes:sha256                            @ 2019/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emailsha256"
```

Now I want to get a version if **md5** is **emialmd5**.
I am using now `bigtable.ValueFilter("emialmd5")`  in my golang code. In the result,
I am getting just one cell in the response which is

```
  hashes:md5                               @ 2023/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emialmd5"
```

Is there any way through which i can get my expected answer as below:

```
  hashes:md5                               @ 2023/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emialmd5"
  hashes:sha1                              @ 2023/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emailsha1"
  hashes:sha256                            @ 2019/06/17-10:58:39.711000
    "emailsha256"
```